# What is the proper way to format the JSON string for FullCalendar events from a db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am attempting to render a `FullCalendar` (1.5.3) in my MVC application as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    titleFormat: { day: '' },
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: "/Schedule/GetCal"
});
```

The resulting `JSON` string from `/Schedule/GetCal` looks like this:

```
{id:"5BFAA9C3-9437-49B0-A657-5DA47CDEA409",projectId:"5BFAA9C3-9437-49B0-A657-5DA47CDEA409",title:"Orem City Parking Lot",start:"2012-07-11",end:"",allDay:"true",type:"goal",textColor:"white",backgroundColor:"green",borderColor:"black",crew:""},
{id:"33910A42-C5F0-42FA-AB36-C315BDDAF964",projectId:"33910A42-C5F0-42FA-AB36-C315BDDAF964",title:"Thanksgiving Point - Buster",start:"2012-07-28",end:"",allDay:"true",type:"goal",textColor:"white",backgroundColor:"green",borderColor:"black",crew:""}
```

It does not render any events on the page.  However, when I call it like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    titleFormat: { day: '' },
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: [{id:"5BFAA9C3-9437-49B0-A657-5DA47CDEA409",projectId:"5BFAA9C3-9437-49B0-A657-5DA47CDEA409",title:"Orem City Parking Lot",start:"2012-07-11",end:"",allDay:"true",type:"goal",textColor:"white",backgroundColor:"green",borderColor:"black",crew:""},
            {id:"33910A42-C5F0-42FA-AB36-C315BDDAF964",projectId:"33910A42-C5F0-42FA-AB36-C315BDDAF964",title:"Thanksgiving Point - Buster",start:"2012-07-28",end:"",allDay:"true",type:"goal",textColor:"white",backgroundColor:"green",borderColor:"black",crew:""}
   ]
});
```

It works as expected.  What do I need to change in the formatting of the `JSON` string?  Or, in how I call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helped me to figure it out: [ASP.Net MVC, jQuery and FullCalendar](http://jrmcconnell.com/2010/07/19/asp-net-mvc-jquery-and-fullcalendar/)

Apparently with `FullCalendar` 1.5.3 and `asp.net mvc` you need to return a `List<>` that has been converted `.ToArray()`, then serialized in `JSON`.  As soon as I did that, the results appeared in the calendar as I expected.

I used `alert(data)` to see the results in the browser and instead of the string I posted above it was

```
{Object},{Object}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `/Schedule/GetCal` script needs to return an array of events - denoted by the square brackets surrounding the set of events in a JSON string.

Currently it looks like you're just returning a comma separated list of events which isn't being interpreted how you expect it to.

Your output needs to look like this:

> ["0",{"allDay":"","title":"Go To Work","id":"821","end":"2011-06-06 14:00:00","start":"2011-06-06 06:00:00"},"1",{"allDay":"","title":"Party at Toms","id":"822","end":"2011-06-10 21:00:00","start":"2011-06-10 16:00:00"}]

Comment: I tried both with and without square brackets.  Neither worked.